# Permutate every combination to the letter

Tags: java, performance, permutation

```
public class StringPermutation {    
    public static List<String> getPermutation(String input) {
        List<String> collection = null;   
        if (input.length() == 1) {
            collection = new ArrayList<String>();
            collection.add(input);
            return collection;
        } else {
            collection = getPermutation(input.substring(1));
            Character first = input.charAt(0);
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String str : collection) {
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                    String item = str.substring(0, i) + first
                            + str.substring(i);
                    result.add(item);
                }
                String item = str.concat(first.toString());
                result.add(item);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> test = StringPermutation.getPermutation ("CAT");
        System.out.println (test);
    }
}
```

The code above permutes a string it's given. For example, given `cat`, it returns [`cat, act, atc, cta, tca, tac`], which is excellent but is it possible for you guys to please edit my code so that it also shows the subsets of the letters too, i.e [`cat, act, atc, cta, tca, tac] and [at, ta, tc, ca, ac, ct, c, a, t`]?

Comment: Homework? . Please tag it as such. By the way, I believe this question has been answered multiple times here but I suggest that you try to work though it yourself (which is the point behind a hw)

Comment: lol this is not a homework am creating an android app.. this is just a section of the program.i can send u the apk to test it out, but its not complete yet. If its been answered can u please put the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first generate all subsets of letters and then generate all permutations for given subset:

```
Set<String> subsets;

public void generateSubsets(String current, String left) {
    if (left.length() == 0) {
        subsets.add(current);
    } else {
        generateSubsets(current, left.substring(1));
        generateSubsets(current + left.charAt(0), left.substring(1));
    }
}

List<String> allPermutations(String word) {
    subsets = new HashSet<String>();
    generateSubsets("", word);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String subset : subsets) {
        result.addAll(StringPermutation.getPermutation(subset));
    }
    return result;
}
```

So if you have "cat"
Subsets will be: "", "c", "a", "t", "ca", "ct", "tc", "cat"
And then you get permutations for every subset.
Regarding efficiency, it is not the best solution, but you can improve it.

Comment: You re right is not efficient is causing Java out of heap space error. Am thinking of sending it to a text file. Thank Though

Comment: if you have suggestions in Building an efficient and reliable android app let me know